# RequireJS - Shim multiple co-dependent non-AMD modules

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd, shim

I have two external files/modules from a 3rd party which I cannot alter or otherwise control. They are fetched on-demand from the 3rd party's servers at browser runtime when a page loads.

The first file/module is the 3rd party library itself, which I can set up to export it's variable in the shim config (below), we'll call that variable "thirdpartylib". "thirdpartylib" is normally off of the window object.

The second file/module is a setup file which attaches configuration variables to the "thirdpartylib" object created by the first file. For example it adds "thirdpartylib.foo = 'x';" to the original object and other configuration options.

I need to be able to shim BOTH files, have the second setup file depend on the first one, using it's export value, then export the object with it's additions/alterations.

I then need to be able to depend on the second module (setup file) in my own custom code and run it's init method from there.

```
require(['thirdpartylibsetup'], function(thirdpartylib) {
    thirdpartylib.init();
});
```

In my shim config I tried the following:

```
shim: {
    'thirdpartylib': {
        exports: 'thirdpartylib'
    },
    'thirdpartylibsetup': {
        deps: ['thirdpartylib'],
        exports: 'thirdpartylib'
    }
```

I tried it both using and not using an exports on the "thirdpartylibsetup" module (which also comes from the 3rd party). The 'thirdpartylibsetup' module doesn't see the thirdpartylib variable at runtime.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Conceptually, what you show should work. However, it is easy to get things wrong due to typos, or problems elsewhere than in what you show in your question, or quirks in the libraries you are using. Having a [mcve] would help.